# How do I enable http method DELETE from apache2 server on virtual box

Tags: rest, http, methods, apache2, sql-delete

I can not send DELETE from my server to the Client, POST works perfectly fine. I am using UBUNTU machine on Virtual BOX, In the wire shark I get the stuff bellow:

```
OPTIONS /wm/staticflowentrypusher/json HTTP/1.1 
HTTP    73  HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed  (application/json)
```

Instead of OPTIONS it should be DELETE, I saw that I have to enable it from the Apache2 files but I can not figure out which one and also can not find the right thing in order for me to enable it. I am using HTML and JAVA-SCRIPTS.

Answer (score 0):

Apache doesn't limit the methods unless you have a specfic <LIMIT> tag in your config as in:

```
<Limit GET POST HEAD>
 Allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE OPTIONS>
 Deny from all
</Limit>
```

So check your .htaccess file in the web directory and also check your config in your apache conf directory.  Otherwise it might be whatever scripting/automation server you're using on the backend creating this restriction.